# How to make cc look into /usr/local/include for header files

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header

I encountered this problem while installing some python modules in which had dependencies on their own C libraries. The problem is, `cc` is not looking into `/usr/local/include` at all for header files. I made it work for one of those (thinking it was a problem of the modules) by adding `/usr/local/include` as one of the external include directories.

Then, to test, I wrote a simple `hello.c` file and added `#include "fftw3.h"` / `#include <fftw3.h>` and it failed to compile if I didn't explicitly add `-I/usr/local/include`.

I added a line in my `~/.bash_profile` to export the include the directory path to `$PATH`; didn't work either.

So, my question is, how do I make `cc` look for header files in `/usr/local/include` (or, for that matter, in any custom directory) always without passing `-I` flag?

FYI: I'm using macbook pro running OSX 10.11

Comment: No expert on this, so I can't give an answer, but a hint: assuming your `cc` is actually `gcc`, google for "gcc specs"

Comment: _"... and it failed to compile if I didn't explicitly add `-I/usr/local/include` ..."_ That's exactly what you're supposed to do.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well, my `cpp` is actually looking in `/usr/local/include` by default...

Comment: The c compiler is supposed to look into `/usr/local/include` by default, isn't it?

Comment: maybe apple begs to differ ... but given that info, it's probably `clang`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using GCC then you have three environment variables you can use:

- `CPATH`
- `C_INCLUDE_PATH`
- `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`

Take a look [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html).

EDIT: since you specified you are working with OS X (hence Clang), they should be supported too, take a look ad the end [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html). It's not uncommon to have Clang mimic GCC specs just to help in compatibility.

Comment: Are these supposed to be blank if I never touched them?

Comment: @Sidmeister: Yes, I guess so. They're used to provide custom behavior.

Comment: Adding it to `CPATH` did it for me. New problem now, missing libraries. But thats for another time I guess.

Comment: @Sidmeister: take a look at `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I did, `export  LIBRARY_PATH...` and it worked. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should invest some time in understanding build systems. For example gnu make. Here, look at this:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall
DEPS = primes.h
OBJ = go.o primes.o

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

go: $(OBJ)
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

This gives you:

- The freedom to add any compiler you want. In your case that would be cc, in this example it is gcc.
- use cflags to control to adjust the compiler - in the example -Wall will turn on the warnings
- make your build work reproducible
- prepare recipe with complex rules for compilation as your application grow

More information is available [here](http://www.gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/12_Compiling_linking_Makefile_header_files.html).